# Pydev + Django workflow. Local(test) + remote synchronization. Using git with django

Tags: django, eclipse, git, workflow, pydev

I'm new to django and my very first project is my blog. I wonder how django developers who use pydev normally synchronize with remote hosting server, updating their sites?

I also would like to know, how do you combine usage of git with a django project? Should I just make a repository for the entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my company we've got an entire git repository for each project, including the Django sources that are put in the `PYTHONPATH` for each project, making Django versions project dependant. The folder structure is something like:

```
/.git
/projectname/app1
/projectname/app2
/projectname/manage.py
/django-lib/django/...
```

As `django-lib` is not a Python module, we include both / and /django-lib in the `PYTHONPATH`. If your project is becoming large, you might want to consider using [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) on your apps.

We've also setup several servers to support the developers. There's a testing server running a central testing database and a setup including Apache with WSGI to make testing on a real server possible, which sometimes is a bit different then the local `manage.py` the developers use before committing their changes.

The testing server is updated with the master branch of our git repository. We've made several scripts to allow all developers to do this without letting them login to the server via SSH, but that is just during pre-release. After release, that server will become our staging server, and we'll remove all scripts from it to make it just like our production server.

Every developer has setup their local project to make sure that it communicates with the central testing database, containing several test data. I myself push my changes from the commandline, but you could also use [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) for this.

When we've got a release, we put it in a separate branch, called 'release' (obviously) and the production server will pull only from that branch. This is done via SSH, but I don't really know how your server setup looks like, so I guess that that last step is entirely up to you.

I hope that this has helped you a bit. I won't say that this is the best workflow possible, but it works for us and you should figure out what works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've almost figured out how this works, just need to read a bit more about git.

Answer (score 1):

Most experienced Django developers use pip(or distribute) and virtualenv deal with all the python packages you might need for your Django projects (including Django itself).

Personally, all I keep in my projects git repository is a bunch of segregated requirements lists generated by pip :

```
. ~/Dev/environs/$PROJECT_NAME/bin/activate
pip freeze > ./docs/requirements/main.list
```

I'm fairly sure most django developers would be familiar with Fabric, which I use for :

- streamlining local interaction with git and,
- pushing to our central repository,
- pulling from our production or test server
- touching the wsgi on the relevant server
- and pretty much any other kind of task you might find yourself using ssh terminal session for.

For those cases where I need to make changes to someone elses django application in order to make it work or suit our purposes, I :

- fork it on github,
- clone from my forked repo
- make the changes
- push it up to my own repo
- and provide merge requests to the original repo owner

This way, i have a repo where i can use pip requirement lists to keep pulling from until the original application owner gets their own repo updated.